# Can Gullveig of the Nordic Ascendant be used as material for the summon of another Gullveig?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Gullveig of the Nordic Ascedant is a Link Monster who's materials say:

> 1 lvl 5 or lower Nordic Monster.

*Does this mean the Gulllveig can be used as material for itself?*

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean the Gulllveig can be used as material for itself?

No it can't.

Link Monsters have no Level nor Rank. From the Wiki on [Link Monsters](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Link_Monster), emphasis mine:

> Link Monsters have a Link Rating in place of a Level or Rank. [...]
>
> **Link Monsters do not possess Levels or Ranks**, therefore they cannot be used as material for a Ritual, Synchro, or Xyz Summon. Also, Level or Rank-modifying cards such as "Harmonic Waves", "Feedback Warrior", or "Xiangsheng Magician" do not affect Link Monsters.

As Gullveig *specifically* asks for a Level 5 or lower monster that means you can't use her as a link material to summon another copy of Gullveig.